# how can I get a DISTINCT list of users who have commented (polymorphic association) on a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

User `has_many` comments. Comment are in the `comments` table (polymorphic).

```rb
User.where("comments.commentable_type = ? AND comments.commentable_id = ?", "Post", post.id).uniq
```

I get:

```
Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 1
TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Distinct
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:25:in `rescue in visit'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:133:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:41:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `map'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:36:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `accept'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:496:in `inspect'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Without `.uniq`, it works, except I get duplicates, therefore, I can try:

```rb
User.where("comments.commentable_type = ? AND comments.commentable_id = ?", "Post", post.id).to_a.uniq
```

And it will work...but I don't like that method! Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Restart the rails server session.

Comment: In my case, I restarted the console.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7399) to the github issue related to the same problem that you face.

If you are using rails 4 try using `.distinct` instead of `.uniq` .

Answer (score 0):

I remember having issues similar, couple things you can do.  First use the SQL distinct (I know it is suppose to be similar to the uniq). Second (I know this is not the best way), you can just select it all then just use regular array uniq functions to filter it just like how you would filter a normal array (this is to just get things going).

Comment: the question is, how do you add SQL distinct to a where clause.. that's what .uniq is supposed to be doing behind the scenes...