# Get distinct values from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get distinct value from this controller. But I am not sure how to succeed.

Here the controller I have try this

```
@count = Present.where('event_id > ?', params[:id]).uniq.pluck(:customer_id)
```

But when I try to do this in my view

```
<% @count.each do | co | %>
  <%= co.customer_id %>
<% end %>
```

I keep having this issues

```
Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Distinct
```

I want to be able to preserve all Present Objects with the event_id equal to the id, but also being able to select only the one with distinct customer_id.

Update: after restarting the server i get the following error

```
undefined method `customer_id' for 1:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to restart your rails server: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7399

Previous [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023088/how-can-i-get-a-distinct-list-of-users-who-have-commented-polymorphic-associati)

**Update:**

From the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck): When using `pluck`, "The values has same data type as column"

Change loop to:

```
<% @count.each %> do |i| 
  <%= i %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just restarted my server and here what i get undefined method `customer_id' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: Means it was trying to call method `customer_id` on Fixnum (number). Change your loop to: `<% @count.each %> do |i| <%= i %> <% end %>`

Comment: So it will return the customer_id values at all times?

Comment: Take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck. Its return value has "same data type as `customer_id`"